# is there gnu MS-Windows version asm/ioctls.h?

Tags: linux, windows, assembly, gnu, ioctl

I need to port a Linux program which includes <asm/ioctls.h> to MS-Windows  Is there a gnu window version of those header files?

Comment: Replacing the header file is probably the least of your worries.  It just defines a bunch of constants to be passed to the `ioctl` system call.  But having those constants defined won't help you when the actual runtime OS call won't understand them anyway.

Comment: To help with a deeper understanding of IOCTL, at a high level it is not necessary for the `ioctl` function to understand any of the codes even on the correct platform.  Instead it passes them through to the driver which handles the file/special file/device you have open and pass as the `fd` parameter of `ioctl`, and only the driver actually needs to recognize them.  So different drivers on the same OS may not even recognize the same set of codes.  Now, the OS `ioctl` function is responsible for access checks, so it does end up doing some matching for security purposes.